# Array of Button in JavaFX using Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

Lets say I have two buttons in the FXML for instance:

```
<Button fx:id="button1" onAction="#onClick1" prefHeight="134.0" prefWidth="134.0"></Button>
<Button fx:id="button2" onAction="#onClick2" prefHeight="134.0" prefWidth="134.0"></Button>
```

and I want to have it as an array of buttons in the controller class. How can I go about and do that? I have tried:

```
public Button button1, button2;
public Button[] arrayButtons = {button1, button2}
```

and also tried making a method:

```
public class controller {
    public Button button1, button2;
    public Button[] arrayButtons;

    public void initializeButtonArray() {
        arrayButtons = new Button[2];
        arrayButtons[1] = button1;
        arrayButtons[2] = button2;
    }
}
```

none of these work as it gives me a runtime exception when I try to do something with the array (ie. arrayButton[1].setText("Test")):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

How can I go about and have an array of Button where the elements are from fx:id?

Comment: Just rename `initializeButtonArray` to `initialize` (or call the `initializeButtonArray()` method from `initialize()`).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

1)@FXML annotation is used cause the Objects are private.In case you make them public there is no need to use @FXML

2)As soon as FXMLLoader has loaded the controller the `initialize` method is called.Inside it you are sure that every object linked with fxml scene graph has been initialized.

Code(Obviously this is one way and you can do it in various other ways):

```
public class controller { 


@FXML
private Button button1;

@FXML
private Button button2;

public Button[] arrayButtons;

@FXML
public void initialize(){ 

initializeButtonArray();

}
 public void initializeButtonArray() { 

    arrayButtons = new Button[2];  
    arrayButtons[1] = button1;
    arrayButtons[2] = button2;
 } 

}
```