# is there any way I can apply this onMouseEntered to all the buttons in the FXML file without actually writing a separate code for each one?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

package PostLogIn;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class PostLogInController {

```
@FXML Button team;

@FXML Button matches;

@FXML Button trainings;

@FXML Button photoGallery;

@FXML Button videoGallery;

@FXML Button results;

@FXML AnchorPane aPane;


public void resize(MouseEvent event) {


    matches.setOnMouseEntered(e->{
        
        matches.setScaleX(2);
        matches.setTranslateX(50);
    });
        matches.setOnMouseExited(e1->{
        matches.setScaleX(1);
        matches.setTranslateX(0);
    });
}
}
```

Comment: There may be a good reason you're doing this, but it seems weird that you're adding the mouse entered and exited listeners in another mouse listener.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of array, I would rather recommend to go with List. It makes the code simple to handle further.

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class PostLogInController {

    @FXML
    Button team;
    @FXML
    Button matches;
    @FXML
    Button trainings;
    @FXML
    Button photoGallery;
    @FXML
    Button videoGallery;
    @FXML
    Button results;
    @FXML
    AnchorPane aPane;

    private List<Button> buttons;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        buttons = Stream.of(team, matches, trainings, photoGallery, videoGallery, results).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public void resize(MouseEvent event) {
        buttons.forEach(b->{
            b.setOnMouseEntered(e->{
                b.setScaleX(2);
                b.setTranslateX(50);
            });
            b.setOnMouseExited(e->{
                b.setScaleX(1);
                b.setTranslateX(0);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be much easier in CSS. Just do the following in an external CSS file:

```css
.button:hover {
    -fx-scale-x: 2 ;
    -fx-translate-x: 50 ;
}
```

You can declare the CSS file directly in the FXML with a `styleSheets` attribute on the root element.

Comment: tried it too and it worked, thanks @James_D... I had the CSS file but just with the background and  radius properties, I added now your code and it looks good

Answer (score 1):

You could put them all in an array, and use a for-each loop to add the listener, but it would make it harder to refer to each individually:

```
...

public class PostLogInController {

    Button[] buttons = new Button[6];

    AnchorPane aPane;

    public void resize(MouseEvent event) {

        for(Button b : buttons) {
            b.setOnMouseEntered(e->{
                b.setScaleX(2);
                b.setTranslateX(50);
            });
            b.setOnMouseExited(e1->{
                b.setScaleX(1);
                b.setTranslateX(0);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok after the answer from @Jaden and taking a look at the [Array of Button in JavaFX using Scene Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660902/array-of-button-in-javafx-using-scene-builder) I came out with a solution that worked out perfectly :

```
    @FXML Button team;

    @FXML Button matches;

    @FXML Button trainings;

    @FXML Button photoGallery;

    @FXML Button videoGallery;

    @FXML Button results;

    @FXML AnchorPane aPane;

    public Button[] arrayButton;
    
    @FXML

    public void initialize(){ 

    initializeButtonArray();

    }
    
    private void initializeButtonArray() {

        arrayButton = new Button[6];

        arrayButton[0] = matches;

        arrayButton[1] = team; 

        arrayButton[2] = trainings;

        arrayButton[3] = photoGallery;

        arrayButton[4]  = videoGallery;

        arrayButton[5] = results;

    }


    
        public void resize(MouseEvent event) {

            for(Button b : arrayButton) {
                b.setOnMouseEntered(e->{
                    b.setScaleX(2);
                    b.setTranslateX(50);
                });
                b.setOnMouseExited(e1->{
                    b.setScaleX(1);
                    b.setTranslateX(0);
                });
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this document from Oracle on [handling events in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/convenience_methods.htm#CIHCIJHJ), I don't know why you won't create a Mouse Event handler class that handles the specific action, and then pass the same instance to all your buttons:

In the document, they show the following example:

```
final Circle circle = new Circle(radius, Color.RED); 

circle.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
        System.out.println("Mouse entered"); 
    }
});
```

For you, this means that, instead of creating an anonymous `EventHandler`, you create your own class that implements that interface (or extend some `EventHandler` adapter class) and your resizing code there (inside the `handle` method).